# What is API? I have an example code with 2 lines here, let's use this code to discuss

Tags: swift, api, dictionary

I've searched a while of the meaning of the API. Yes, I kind of know it from the general overview, it is the Application Programming Interface. It is an Interface for the Application and only used by programmers, users don't need it. App can change, but API keeps, .......... I can describe it by so many metaphors. But what is it? I still don't know.

There is the last part of the section **Collection Types** from the [official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105)

> If you need to use a dictionary’s keys or values with an **API** that takes an Array instance, initialize a new array with the keys or values property:

```
let airportCodes = [String](airports.keys)
// airportCodes is ["YYZ", "LHR"]

let airportNames = [String](airports.values)
// airportNames is ["Toronto Pearson", "London Heathrow"]
```

Could someone explain the API to me by this example? What is the API here? How it works?

Thanks a lot

Comment: API = `Application Program Interface` ... it is something you call with inputs and get an output

Comment: API can refer both to the entire body of functions, or it can be used to refer to an individual function. In this case, the documentation is using it to refer to a specific function, one that takes an array instance.

Comment: @Gody Gray Thanks For the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API is something which can be used without you writing a code for the same thing over and over again. `let airportNames = [String](airports.values)` says you can append this array with an array of airportNames which is a string. If you wanted to do this by yourself, you had to first initialise the array, then add it. The `.values` will have it's own function and implementation behind this. It eases the way you write your code.

Comment: Is API and function? Because function can also be used so many times after it has been written. What's the different with a function?

Comment: It's a collection of functions which are made in a way so that you can use them repeatedly in different projects without having to re write them. You are right. Function can also be re written, but certain API's do save a lot of your time and makes it easier to code. This is a very small example of an API. Some API's written by marvellous devs are too too much to write by yourself for every new project.

Comment: So, API can be considered as some Mature and reliable functions, be used many times to speed up the development.

Comment: Yep!! Your code will be cleaner and readable and compact. Which is also a great desirable quality of a decent dev. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and help. ")

Comment: Anytime. Happy coding! :)